# Add TIO link to messages!

Tags: code-golf, internet

It's annoying when you have to search for a language homepage, get its link, and add it to your SE comment/answer, right? Let's write a script to do that for you!

## Challenge

For each language name (intentional or not) in the input, replace it with the markdown link to the language home page, defined by TIO.

## Rules

- (important) You can only connect to `https://tio.run`.
- Use the language list on TIO at the time your program is run.
- The input is a string. Assume no newline (because multiline messages can't have markdown anyway). Unicode characters may be inside the string because they can exist in chat messages ([example](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42577306#42577306)).
- The input is valid markdown, but it is unlikely that this is related to the challenge.
- You can assume there is no link inside the input. (Whoops, I missed this when the challenge was in the sandbox, thanks [mercator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76878) for pointing that out. As far as I can see this should not invalidate any existing answers)
- Case sensitive or insensitive, whatever you choose.
- Only word breaks (not both adjacent to an English letter) are considered. (for example, `matlab` should not be converted to `matlab`, `47` should be converted to `47`)

  > Note: It's too hard to define what's a "character" in Unicode, so your program can detect a word break or not if one of the two surrounding characters are not printable ASCII.
- Only use markdown `[...](...)`, not HTML link `<a href="...">...</a>` because the latter doesn't work in chat.
- Markdown components (`*` / `_` for italic, `**` for bold, `---` for strikethrough (in chat)) in messages should not matter, because AFAIK there are no languages with such names on TIO.
- Use the language name (`Wolfram Language (Mathematica)`), not language ID.
- No overlapping replacement.
- In case there are multiple output, pick whichever. See example below.
- Although by default chat markdown doesn't allow links in code blocks, for simplicity I would just assume that they don't need to be treated specially.

## Winning criteria

[code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf).

## Test cases

```
Input -> Output
matlab -> matlab
47 -> [4](https://github.com/urielieli/py-four)[7](https://esolangs.org/wiki/7)
/// -> [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////)
//// -> [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////)/ or /[///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////)
////// -> [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////)[///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////) or //[///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////)/
Uṅıċȯḋė -> Uṅıċȯḋė
```

## More test cases

(suggested by [Adám](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/43319/ad%c3%a1m). Any replacement is fine as long as they don't overlap (valid markdown source))

```
\///
S.I.L.O.S.I.L.O.S
Del|m|t
Del|m|tcl
```

Comment: "AFAIK there are no languages with such names on TIO" - congratulations, now there are going to be a dozen within a week because of this

Comment: Why can matlab not become [matl]ab but 47 can become [4][7]?

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Because word break.

Comment: Looks like people hate word breaks. I don't know. 2 downvotes already. [blame-sandbox]

Comment: @user202729 https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolaugKDOvRKMoVS8tMy8lMSdHo0gpJikmJSZJSUdBycRcSVPz/38A

Comment: @HyperNeutrino I told you, [blame-sandbox]. I don't know about the behavior of `\b` before asking, and now I can't invalidate answers.

Comment: `matl` isn't the name of a supported language. It's `MATL`. So the `matlab` test case doesn't cover the word break rule for answers that are case-sensitive.

Comment: And what should happen with input like `a2sable` or `Ada (GNAT)foo`? Are there word breaks at the start/end of those language names? And when you say the input is valid markdown, does this mean the input can also be a name that's _already_ linked, like `[4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4)`? What should happen then?

Comment: @mercator Hopefully fixed? I don't understand, what's the problem with those inputs?

Comment: Looks good, yes. :) The problem with those inputs is I'm still not entirely sure what word breaks are. Is there a break in the middle of `a2`? The way it's described now seems to me like it's a word break if the language name is on the right (`2`), but not if the language is on the left (`a`). If there _is_ a word break, none of the answers pass. And I'm wondering if I'm going to spend the effort trying to fix my answer. :P Or if I can convince you to drop the rule. ;)

Comment: @mercator But existing answers... I will test them (and probably change the rules accordingly) later.

Answer (score 6):

## Javascript (ES6) + jQuery, 247 bytes

```js
s=>c=>$.getJSON('https://tio.run/static/645a9fe4c61fc9b426252b2299b11744-languages.json',data=>{for(l of Object.values(data))s=s.replace(eval(`/([^a-zA-Z]|^)${l.name.replace(/[\\/+.|()]/g,"\\$&")}(?![a-zA-Z])/g`),`$1[${l.name}](${l.link})`);c(s)})
```

### Explanation (less golfed)

```js
s=>c=>
// Load TIO languages using jQuery
$.getJSON('https://tio.run/static/645a9fe4c61fc9b426252b2299b11744-languages.json',data=>{
  // For every language
  for(l of Object.values(data)) {
    // Construct a regex that matches the language name
    var regex = eval(`/([^a-zA-Z]|^)${l.name.replace(/[\\/+.|()]/g,"\\$&")}(?![a-zA-Z])/g`
    // Replace all occurences of the language name with the language name and link
    s=s.replace(regex),`$1[${l.name}](${l.link})`)
  }
  // Return using callback
  c(s);
});
```

```js
f=
s=>c=>$.getJSON('https://tio.run/static/645a9fe4c61fc9b426252b2299b11744-languages.json',data=>{for(l of Object.values(data))s=s.replace(eval(`/([^a-zA-Z]|^)${l.name.replace(/[\\/+.|()]/g,"\\$&")}(?![a-zA-Z])/g`),`$1[${l.name}](${l.link})`);c(s)})

f("47")(console.log);
f("///")(console.log);
f("////")(console.log);
f("//////")(console.log);
f("Uṅıċȯḋė")(console.log);
f("\///")(console.log);
f("S.I.L.O.S.I.L.O.S")(console.log);
f("Del|m|t")(console.log);
f("Del|m|tcl")(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python + Selenium, 496 bytes

I decided using the front end of the website would be cooler.  And since nearly everything is loaded via JavaScript, Selenium was my best bet.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from re import*
d=webdriver.Chrome("a.exe")
d.get("https://tio.run/#")
t={e.text.lower():e.get_attribute("data-id")for e in d.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="results"]/div')}
def q(reg):s=reg.group(0);d.get("https://tio.run/#"+t[s.lower()]);d.find_element_by_id("permalink").click();a=d.find_elements_by_tag_name("textarea")[4].get_attribute('value');return"["+s+"]("+search(': (ht.*)\n',a).group(1)+")"
print(sub('|'.join(map(escape,t.keys())),q,input(),flags=I))
```

## Pseudo-Ungolfed Version

I thought providing an in-between would be useful for understanding.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import re
import itertools

input = lambda:"47////////"

s = input()
driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://tio.run/#")
temp = {ele.text.lower():ele.get_attribute("data-id")for ele in driver.find_element_by_id("results").find_elements_by_tag_name("div")}
def abc(reg):
    s=reg.group(0)
    driver.get("https://tio.run/#"+temp[s.lower()])
    ele = driver.find_element_by_id("permalink").click()
    a = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("textarea")[4].get_attribute('value')
    return"["+s+"]("+re.search(': (ht.*)\n',a).group(1)+")"
bob = re.sub('|'.join(map(re.escape,temp.keys())),abc,s,flags=re.I)
print(bob)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>291</s> 301 bytes

```python
import json,urllib
s=raw_input().decode('u8');m=json.loads(urllib.urlopen('https://tio.run/languages.json').read());n=0
while n<len(s):
 for l in sorted(m,None,lambda x:m[x]['name'],1):
  L=m[l]['name'];r='[%s](%s)'%(L,m[l]['link'])
  if s.find(L,n)==n:s=s[:n]+r+s[n+len(L):];n+=len(r)-1
 n+=1
print s
```

Doesn't strictly speaking follow the rules, since it doesn't consider word breaks. It always takes the longest possible match first.